# Compute the Limit[G[n]/2^(n^2)] as n goes to infinity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I defined the function G[n] by inputting:

```
G[n_] := Product[2^n - 2^i, {i, 0, n - 1}]
```

I want to know the limit as n goes to infinity of G[n]/2^(n^2) so I input:

```
Limit[G[n]/2^(n^2), n -> ∞]
```

Mathematica returns 1, which I don't think is true.

Comment: Your function is `f[n_] = Simplify[G[n]/2^(n^2), n>0]` which simplifies to `QPochhammer[2^(-n), 2, n]` and `Limit[f[n], n->Infinity] == QPochhammer[0, 2, Infinity] == QPochhammer[0, 2] == 1` evaluates to `True`. Trying to verify this numerically gets unbearably slow for very large `n`.

Comment: Greetings Bob Hanlon.  But it is obvious that the limit is NOT 1.

Comment: Perhaps, but odd things happen at Infinity.

Comment: Just an observation. `QPochhammer[2^(-n), 2, n] /. n -> 1000.0` gives `1.0`, whereas `QPochhammer[2^-n, 2, n] /. n -> 1000 // N` gives `0.288788`.

Answer (score 5):

First note that the sequence $G_n:=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (2^n-2^i)$ is A002884 in OEIS.  Writing
$$G_n= 2^{n(n-1)/2} \prod_{i=1}^n (2^i-1) $$
we see that
$$ H_n:=2^{-n^2/2} G_n =2^{-n(n+1)/2} \prod_{i=1}^n (2^i-1) $$
Mathematica verifies that
$$ H_n=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-2^{-i})$$
Thus
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} H_n = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-2^{-i})=0.28878\,80950\ldots$$

Comment: Just to add to that, the closed form for the limit is `In[40]:= Product[1 - 2^-i, {i, 1, ∞}]

Out[40]= QPochhammer[1/2, 1/2]

In[41]:= N[%]

Out[41]= 0.2887880950866024`